# What is the best solution for multi tenancy in Django?

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant

I'm working on a property management app in Django that will eventually have multiple companies, each with multiple users. I want to be able to have each company have it's own path. For example, `mysite.com/company1/property/1/`

Eventually though I'd like to pool the entries from each different companies onto one site - so I'd like to keep everything in one database.

One way that I can think of to do this is to set up a Company model and then have each property have a ForeignKey for Company. But then I'm not sure how best to code views to only show or modify for the current company.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

EDIT: Ideally, I'd like to create a view/helper method that performs a query that limits the resulting properties to the company and then passes the queryset and request to another view. I'd like to have a URL structure like: `mysite.com/company1/listproperties` . So this function would limit the properties to Company1, and then I'd want to use the second part of the URL to determine which view to use (listProperties, searchProperties), and pass the remaining as arguments. However I'm unsure how to code this first filtering view and the URL handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several things you're asking here. 1: how to model relationships between models, 2: how to display a view for a single company

For problem one, Django handles problems like this in data modeling with relationships. Here's the documentation tutorial for relationships: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#relationships

In your example, a Property to Company relationship is 'many-to-one', meaning that a Company has many Properties but a Property has only one Company. In Django(the link I gave you) all that is typically done is a foreign key in the model that is the 'many', or in your case Property. Here's what I would do:

```py
class Property(models.Model):
  owner = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

This also allows you to query relationships, solving the second problem.

If I have a Company `c`, I can access all the Properties associated with it like this:

```py
c.property_set.all()
# => [Property <MyProperty>, Property <OtherProperty>, ...]
```

That's a query you would do in the view and then pass to the template.

Here's a Django-provided example of this very thing(many-to-one) that you may find useful: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I had in mind (vis a vis using a ForeignKey and then querying the subset of companies. I'm curious as to whether there is a way for me to factor this process out. Could I create a view/helper function that performs this query and then passes the queryset and request to another view? I'd like to keep the `mysite.com/company1/listproperties` url structure. Then have a `filterCompany(request,company)` method that handles the preliminary filtering, and then have a `listProperties()` view that takes in the filtered queryset and does the work it needs to do. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not fully sure what you're asking, but an example query could be this: `Company.objects.get(pk=3).property_set.all()`. Given a company ID(pk=3) it gets all the properties(assuming the data model I had above). To get a specific one, `Company.objects.get(pk=3).property_set.get(pk=4)`. Now you give it a company ID and property ID and possibly return something.

Comment: I want to avoid coding the company part of the query into each of my views. I'd rather abstract that out if possible, so that I don't need to `Company.object.get(pk=comp)` in every view. I'd rather have a view that does that, and then pass the query set to listProperty etc. and do subsequent filtering from that view. Make sense?

Comment: That does kind of make sense, but all you need is functions, then. `def getCompany(id): Company.objects.get(pk=id)`, `def getProperties(id): Company.objects.get(pk=id).property_set.all()`, `def getProperty(cid, pid): Company.objects.get(pk=cid).property_set.get(pk=pid)`. Not hard to do. Or you may be interested in class-based view inheritance here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/. That's how you inherit stuff from views(like companies, etc.) Nothing more to say except read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just trying to make my code DRY as I understand that is best practice and will abstraction will reduce repetition and work down the road. I really appreciate the added direction - will look into Class-based views.